# Why does predecessor(zero) need to be zero in Church numerals?

Tags: lo.logic, lambda-calculus

My question may be similar to: [Why naturals instead of integers?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/why-naturals-instead-of-integers), but it is more specific.

I am trying to learn lambda calculus. All the books make a big deal about how it was necessary that predecessor(zero) == zero and it was very tricky to get it right.

Why was that necessary? Can someone point me to some literature, or, better yet, give me a 30 sec explanation?

The only thing I can figure out is that this resulted in the naturals being closed under subtraction, but at a cost of having subtraction being a non one-to-one mapping from the natural numbers to themselves.

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: I think the answer is that this is the only natural definition for predecessor. It must be defined to be some natural number, but any other number seems ridiculous.

Comment: “All the books make a big deal about how it was necessary that predecessor(zero) == zero and it was very tricky to get it right.”  Is that true?  I thought that it is trivial to define predecessor(zero) as any term you want (even a term which is not a Church numeral), and it is defined as zero just because it is slightly more natural than other choices.

Answer (score 10):

The other reason (than the one already stated) for `pred 0 = 0` are the (all too often unstated) *requirements* that

1. `pred` be a total function from `nat` to `nat`
2. `pred succ n = n` be true.
3. `pred` be as close to injective as possible.
4. `pred` be as close to a monotone decreasing function as possible.

It is that last requirement which really 'seals the deal' in forcing `pred 0 = 0`, since that is the choice which minimizes the distance to not being monotone decreasing.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the thirty second explanation for why subtraction "should be" saturating. First, suppose that we have $a, b, s \in \mathbb{N}$.

1. The subtraction $a - b$, when it exists, is the solution $s$ to the equation $s + b = a$.
2. Truncated subtraction is the supremum of the set of solutions to the equation $s + b \leq a$.
3. That is, when $b > a$, no solutions $s + b = a$ exist, and the supremum of an empty set of natural numbers is 0. Otherwise the supremum will just be the subtraction.
4. So saturating subtraction is left adjoint to addition (i.e., $a - b \leq s \iff a \leq s + b$), and is hence a natural definition.
5. Predecessor is just subtracting 1, so it should be saturating too.

I learned about this from Martin Escardo, who also recommended Lawvere's [*Metric spaces, generalized logic and closed categories*](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/1/tr1.pdf) as a nice exposition of this and related ideas.

I should add that this adjunction is nice when doing interactive theorem proving. Proofs involving subtraction typically require case distinctions (i.e., you need to case on whether $b > a$ when proving someting about $a - b$), and furthermore subtraction does not have good associativity or commutativity properties.

In contrast, addition on the natural numbers behaves much better, and you can often use this adjunction to massage a proof obligation into a form which is easier to work with.

Answer (score 6):

In typed $\lambda$-calculus with sums the most natural type for the predecessor function would be (in Haskell parlance)

```
pred :: Nat -> Maybe Nat
```

so that it can return `Nothing` when applied to `0` and `Just n` when applied to the successor of `n`. In untyped $\lambda$-calculus we could just ignore the types, but would still have to invent some way of encoding members of the type `Maybe Nat`, which would just complicate matters. It is easier to "fudge it" and define predecessor so that it maps numerals to numerals.

Comment: Nitpicking: In Haskell, type names must be capitalized.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Duly noted.